# InDesign Script for importing idml to indd document

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-server

I am using InDesign Server and a soap based application to communicate through the server.

I am able to get all fields of form used in indd document and also able to replace its text/value.

Now, I am looking to get all images used in indd doc and provide upload images options at my application and able to replace the images by user selected images. Can anyone provide script for identify and replace the images.

Secondly, for backward compatibility I have idml of an indd doc. Now how to import or open this idml and convert it to indd doc through script.

Thirdly, how to convert pdf into indd doc.

Please help me with these scripts.

Answer (score 0):

To an IDML file into an .indd file, simply open it and save it

```
set theIDMLFile to "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:someidmlfile.idml"

tell application "InDesignServer"
    set convertedIDMLDoc to open alias theIDMLFile
    tell convertedIDMLDoc
        save to ((characters 1 thru -6 of theIDMLFile) & ".indd") as string
    end tell
end tell
```